# JPA2.0 using Jboss runtime libraries (hibernate) failing

Tags: jpa-2.0, jboss7.x

I am using JSF with icefaces components and using JPA2.0 for calls to database. Since I am using JBOSS AS 7.1 server, I am using hibernate.persistence from runtime library. But it is failing with below error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance

The full stack trace:

```
13:34:08,316 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/job-applicant.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$2.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.initializeInstance(WebComponentInstantiator.java:94) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:86) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.jsf.JsfInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JsfInjectionProvider.java:69) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:223) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getCurrentSelectedValues(MenuRenderer.java:648) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectManyCheckboxListRenderer.java:122) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.icefaces.impl.renderkit.RendererWrapper.encodeChildren(RendererWrapper.java:49) [icefaces.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Hibernate cannot unwrap interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.unwrap(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1173) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.unwrap(AbstractEntityManager.java:68) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.injectors.PersistenceContextInjectionSource$PersistenceContextJndiInjectable.getReference(PersistenceContextInjectionSource.java:188) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:104) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:106) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 54 more
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="jobApplication">

<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 
<jta-data-source>java:/OracleJINDI</jta-data-source>
    <class>org.icefaces.training.applicant.model.EmployeesEntity</class>
<class>org.icefaces.training.applicant.model.Employee</class>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
      <property name="use_sql_comments" value="true"/>


  </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Managed  bean that calls

```java
  private String resume;
    private String valuen;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName= "jobApplication")
    EntityManagerFactory emf;


    public String getValuen() {

        //EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jobApplication");
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            EmployeeService service = new EmployeeService(em);
            Employee emp = service.findEmployee((long)207);

            return emp.getLastName();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working: I had to replace `@PersistenceContext` with `@PersistenceUnit`